# Side sliding tabs in iPhone/iPad application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to create a side sliding tabs (like the menu in WP7; I'm not sure what the correct term is) for iPhone/iPad applications? I haven't implemented any code yet, right now I'm assuming that it could probably be done with multiple vertical UIScrollViews within a horizontal UIScrollView.

I've seen this kind of menu in iPad applications (Discovr Music/Movies), and would like to implement it in iPhone if it is possible. Also, is this kind of menu against any of Apple's UX policies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and you can do it.

For example:

```
UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 460)];
UIView *subView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[wrapper addSubview:subView1];
UIView *subView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 460)];
[wrapper addSubview:subView2];
[scrollView setContentSize:wrapper.frame.size];
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES]; //Here's what you want to do!
[scrollView addSubview:wrapper];
```

Didn't test the code, but it should work.

Important is to add Subview to the ScrollView. (It would also work if you don't use a wrapper, but I often use it, because of the size.)

Comment: thank you, this works :)

a few corrections for others that might want to do the same thing though: the 2nd subview's position should be (320,0) instead of (0, 320) and the height should be 460 in the standard view controller if you don't want vertical scrolling :)